# Send notification to assigned user when a task is due in 5 days in DevOps

Tags: azure, devops, power-automate, user-stories

in devops sending out email notifications for work items seems limited with the one's listed below:

[image]

I want to send an email or a notification in teams when a work item has its due date in 5 days. I also check power automate but couldn't find a template for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Email notification in Azure DevOps when a new work item is created for an **issue or a task** by following the below steps :

- login to https://dev.azure.com/
- Select the project on which you want to enable the email notifications --> Go to project settings
- Under project settings, click on notifications --> click on Add new subscription as shown in the below image (this will allow you to create a new rule to configure the alert mechanism)

[image]

- under category select Work --> under Template (select the template based on your requirement)
- In the Edit subscription widget ,Select the **Deliver to** option from the drop down list & select the required role to get notified with the email
- For filter criteria , we have selected the two fields **"Remaining work & Effort "**
- Remaining work fields is used to track **Task** that has less than 120
  Hours (5days *24 Hours).
- Efforts is used to track the **Issues** which
  has less than 120 Hours as shown in the below attached image

[image]

You can refer the attached GIF for reference[image]

Comment: @Sindu_ , If the above provided answer was helpful ? If so could you please mark the accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A task may only be 30 minutes of work, but its Target Date is 10 days from now. I would want an email when it hits the five day mark. It's not particularly Agile, but we have some non-development project management needs that require this type of notification.